# Data location must be "calldata" for parameter in external function,

Tags: solidity, calldata, data-types

I'm getting the following error:

> Data location must be "calldata" for parameter in external function, but "memory" was given.

for the following function:

```
    function _registerAirline(address addr, string memory name)
        external
        requireIsOperational
    {
        require(!airlines[addr].isRegistered, "Airline is already registered");

        airlines[addr] = Airline({
            name: name,
            isFunded: false,
            isRegistered: true
        });

        multiSig.push(addr);
        emit AirlineRegistered(
            airlines[addr].name,
            airlines[addr].isFunded,
            airlines[addr].isRegistered
        );
    }
```

But, when I change the `string memory name` to `string calldata name` and compile, I get an error:

```
ParserError: Expected ',' but got identifier
function _registerAirline(address addr, bytes calldata name)
                                                       ^--^
```

Comment: What version of solidity are you using? At least 0.6.7 and 0.5.17 work as expected and they do not generate that error message.

Comment: full code of contract will give more idea on error because changing memory to calldata work for me fine without error.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you were using solidity 0.4.x. Explicitness of parameters data location was added in [0.5.x](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/050-breaking-changes.html). Change `bytes calldata name` to `bytes name` and it should compile.